# Nested for loop string equivalent in separate Django model Tables

Tags: django, django-models

I have a nested for loop to see where a field from Table Clock equals the field from table Employee, and when this happens run some condition.

This seems extremely intuitive however i seem to be making a fundamental error. My if statement does not execute. I have printed out the each tables values and confirmed that some are equal I have also confirmed that both fields types are strong. Please help.

'''
queryClock = Clock.objects.all()
queryEmployee = Employees.objects.all()

```
    if queryClock.count() > 0 :
        for x in queryClock:           
            for y in queryEmployee:
                # print(type(x.EmployeeNoC),type(y.EmployeeNo))
                # print(x.EmployeeNoC, y.EmployeeNo)
                if x.EmployeeNoC == y.EmployeeNo: 
                    print("yay") 
                    x.hourlyRate = y.rate
                    x.save(update_fields=['hourlyRate'])
                    break
```

'''

```
class Clock(models.Model):
   EmployeeNoC = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, 
   null=True)
   surname = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, 
   null=True)
   code = models.CharField(max_length=25,default='5002', 
   blank=True, null=True)
   space1= models.CharField(max_length=25,default='', 
   blank=True, 
   null=True)
   space2 = models.CharField(max_length=25,default='', 
   blank=True, 
   null=True)
   space3 = models.CharField(max_length=25,default='', 
   blank=True, 
   null=True)
   codeEnd = models.CharField(max_length=25,default='N', 
   blank=True, null=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, 
   null=True)
   monthlyHoursPlaceString = models.CharField(max_length=25, 
   blank=True, null=True)
   monthlyHours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, d 
   decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
   hourlyRate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, 
   decimal_places=2, default=0.00)


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    output = self.monthlyHoursPlaceString.split(":")
    hourPlace = output[0]
    minutePlace = round(int(output[1])/60,2)
    indexValue = [i for i in range(len(hourPlace)) 
    if int(hourPlace[i]) > 0]
     hourPlace = hourPlace[indexValue[0]::]     
     self.monthlyHours = float(hourPlace) + float(minutePlace)
   
    super(Clock, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


def __str__(self):
    if self is not None:
        return '{} : {} : {} : {}: {} '.format(
            str(self.EmployeeNoC),
            str(self.surname),
            str(self.name),
            str(self.monthlyHours),
            str(self.hourlyRate),
            
            )





class Employees(models.Model):
    EmployeeNo = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, 
    null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, 
     null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, 
     null=True)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, 
    default=0.00)

def __str__(self):
    if self is not None:
        return '{} : {} '.format(
            str(self.EmployeeNo),
          
            str(self.rate),)
```

Comment: Provide your models. If you have a foreign key you can simply filter and then then update the queryset

Comment: @RedWheelbarrow I have added the models

Answer (score 0):

Okay so there is nothing incorrect with the code above. My apologies.

It was not working due to importing a csv file with a string that had spaces in it. Thus, when comparing the two: 'a ' != 'a'.

Solution x.x.EmployeeNoC.split()

Always check .csv spacing!!